# How do I break into houses in GTA V?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

Can one break into a house in GTA V?

There's a mission in which Franklin breaks into Michael's house so I was wondering if this activity is an option outside of missions in GTA V.

Comment: Such a missed occasion to name your question "How to break into a house"

Answer (score 4):

You cant. The only break in jobs are during heists or single player and even then there's not the opportunity to pick and choose which building you break in to.

Answer (score 2):

This is just a specific mission. Kind of in the same way that there is a mission to chase down Michael's boat with Franklin (just an example), you won't be doing that activity again. Unless a mission happened to call for that.

Comment: I should add that I haven't owned the game in about a year and this could have been patched in since, but I asked a friend who still owns it and he said there is no such activity.